# How to fix header spacing

Tags: spacing, header-footer

I want to move all headers and text closer to the top of the page, eliminating the empty space above every header. I have tried `\vspace` but I don't think this is the correct solution to the problem.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\rmfamily

\title{\Huge{Predicating the future behaviour of SARS-COVID 19 in Ethiopia and Australia using a deterministic SEIRDV model}}

\begin{document}
\begin{singlespacing}

\end{singlespacing}
\maketitle

\include{Abstract}

\include{Acknowledgements}

\tableofcontents

\include{Introduction}

\include{Methodology}

\include{Raw data}

\include{Processed data}

\include{Limitations}

\include{Recommedations}

\include{Appendix A}

\input{References}

\end{document}
\end{singlespacing}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE from `\documentclass{}` to `\end{document}`

Comment: This is not a MWE. Because we don't have those extra files such as `Introduction.tex`....

Comment: Have you tried  just loading the geometry package and setting the margins to something smaller: `\usepackage[top=1cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}` or whatever you want?

Comment: As shown in figure 2 of the geometry manual, you should use `[includeheadfoot, top=0pt, bottom=0pt]`.